# javascript turned off - can not switch tabs

Tags: 7, blocks

I am experiencing this problem for the first time on drupal 6 install. 
http://www.biome.cz/sampon-proti-vypadavani-vlasu-revita
Here after disabling javascript, it is not possible to load other tabs. The links seems to be ok but after clicking any tab, the content remains the same, even url is changed.

Can anyone help me debugging this?
Thank you

Comment: I cannot reproduce it; the site works fine for me.

Comment: To reproduce it, disable javascript in chrome and reload that page. Try to switch among more tabs. In any of my browsers or computers the tabs won't switch.

Comment: It works with Google Chrome, and JavaScript disabled too.